# SSIS Stuck on Created Execution Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Hi I just want to know what is the cause of this image.

Every time I execute the job in Ctrl M, it is running and the indicator beside it is of color yellow but when I tried to check it in Integration Services it is not running. 
This is manually triggered and not schedule in Ctrl M because this is just on the test server.

Hope someone could help me figure this out.

Thanks  [image]

Comment: need to be a mind reader.....

Comment: How have you defined it to start in CTRL-M? What does the CTRL-M code look like? What does the CTRL-M log say?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but re-deploy of package solved the issue. I think our 3rd party support forgot something to declare. thanks for the time to comment.

Comment: Correction on my answer above, the solution is to free up the memory of server. The SSIS package execution didn't proceed due to 100% CPU utilization.